# Facebook iOS SDK(Graph API) can't access public page information

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-access-token

So I'm trying to get the name of a page with the Facebook graph API using the iOS SDK:

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,name" forKey:@"fields"];

[[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userId] parameters:params HTTPMethod:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
     //do more stuff
}];
```

I'm getting the error

```
error = {
   code = 803;
   message = "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)";
   type = OAuthException;
};
```

My accesstoken is valid and it does work when I'm using the Graph API Explorer with the `GET` request `5120148605?fields=id,name,about,bio`.

Anyone having an idea of this weird behaviour?

Comment: Are you getting `id`? What's the `result` you are getting?

Comment: result is nil. I'm just getting the error, but for my friends it works, just not for pages. Pretty weird.

Comment: What request are you making? `/page_id`? If yes, what's the page_id you are giving?

Comment: I'm using page ids of my timeline. For example `5120148605`.

Comment: I now resolved this by `userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userId]`.

Seems like I need this for pages but not for users. Weird.

Comment: If you've solved the issue; write the anser and accept it to help the others !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now resolved this by `userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userId]`. Seems like I need this for pages but not for users.

I don't know why this is present or if someone else encountered this problem, but that's my way of solving it.